# Добавление элемента списка в TextView

Tags: java, android

Имеется код:

```
    package com.example.asus.myapplication;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.lang.reflect.Array;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private BeerExpert expert = new BeerExpert();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        public void onClickFindBeer(View view){
            TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
            Spinner color = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.color);
            List arr = expert.getBrands(String.valueOf(color.getSelectedItem()));
            for (int i = 0; i<arr.size();i++){
                brands.setText(arr.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

package com.example.asus.myapplication;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BeerExpert {
    List<String> getBrands(String color){
        List<String> brands = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (color.equals("amber")){
            brands.add("Jack Amber");
            brands.add("Red Moose");
        }
        else {
            brands.add("J Pay");
            brands.add("Gout Strout");
        }
        return brands;
    }
}
```

Задача - извлечь из Spinner цвет пива и потом вывести на экран все виды этого цвета. Не понимаю, в чем ошибка в строке `brands.setText(arr.get(i));`
Вроде же как добавляю String.

Comment: Надо указать что за ошибка в тексте вопроса. Наверное это из-за непоняток у компилятора о типе параметра для `setText`. Попробуйте список объявить с указанием типа так: `List<String>`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, все верно. Спасибо большое. А еще вопрос. Как вывести все элементы списка? А то в моем цикле оно почему-то только последний выводит

Comment: если у вас появилась новая проблема - задайте новый вопрос. если вы самостоятельно нашли решение проблемы в вопорсе - оформите решение как ответ. это поможет другим участникам с аналогичной проблемой быстрее решить ее

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii, в цикле вместо `setText` используйте `append`, а лучше соберите весь текст в `StringBuilder` и потом вставьте в `TextView`.